# Compare and Count Two Array Indexes

Tags: arrays, mips

I have only included a portion of my code, what's missing is the array's themselves in the .data section as .word and the exit when the endLoop branch is reached. The goal is to compare two array indexes, arrayA and arrayB, and if there is a match in numbers at a specific index, then the count goes up by one. My issue is that arrayB gets placed in the register after the beq $v1,$v0,count statement, I tried adding a nop before but it increments arrayA's index twice.

```
 main:   
        li $t1, 0               
        li $t2, 0           
        li $t3, 0           
        lw $t6,sizeA($t1) 
        nop

Loop: 
         beq    $t3,$t6,endLoop 
         lw     $v0,arrayA($t1)  
         lw     $v1,arrayB($t1)

         beq    $v1, $v0,count  
         addi   $t1, $t1, 4     
         addi   $t2, $t2, 1
         b      Loop

count: 
       addi     $t2,$t2,1   
       addi     $t3,$t3,1       
       addi     $t1,$t1,4   
       b        Loop
```

Comment: Does your assembler not hide the branch-delay slots?

Comment: In this case I'm using qtSpim, for this specific program the branch-delay slots are supposed to be enabled, otherwise the program works.

Comment: You are hopefully aware that `b` is a special case of `beq $zero, $zero, label`? As in, `b` has a delay slot?

Comment: Ah yes, that was part of the issue, thank you very much.